# Generate Random String with three alphabets of different lengths in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, random

How can I generate a random string with three integers A, B and C containing exactly A letters 'a', B letters 'b' and C letters 'c'?

```
def generate_string(A, B, C):
    // return a string

s = generate_string(2, 5, 1)
// outputs can be
aabbbbbc 
ababbbcb
abcabbbb
and so on....
```

However, I am capable of achieving such kind of functionality using python **random.choice()** function.

```
>>> print(''.join(choice('a'+'b'+'c') for i in range(5)))
aacaa
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @BlackThunder I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to make a string containing those characters, then [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) from that string to shuffle it:

```
from random import sample

s = 'a'*2 + 'b'*5 + 'c'*1

print(''.join(sample(s, k=len(s))))
```

Based on your comment, a function could look something like

```
from itertools import repeat, chain
from random import shuffle

def generate_string(*pairs):
    chars = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(c, n) for n, c in pairs))
    shuffle(chars)
    return ''.join(chars)

print(generate_string((2, 'a'), (5, 'b'), (1, 'c')))
```

If you're only worried about those 3 characters, this can be simplified to

```
def generate_string(a, b, c):
    s = 'a'*a + 'b'*b + 'c'*c
    return ''.join(sample(s, k=len(s)))
```

Comment: But this does not guarantee that there will be 2 a's, 5 b's and 1 c's in each generated string.

Comment: You did the opposite of what I want to achieve. Suppose there is a function that takes three integers (length of characters) as input and generates a string from these lengths.


`def generate_string(length_a, length_b, length_c):
      // return a string`

`s = generate_string(2, 5, 1)

//output
aabbbbbc
ababbbcb
abcabbbb`

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes it does?  `sample` selects without replacement, so we can't end up with more of something than the population has.

Answer (score 0):

Complexity is O(a+b+c) but that will work:

```
from random import shuffle

a = 3
b = 4
c = 5
letters = []

for i in range(a):
  letters.append('a')
for i in range(b):
  letters.append('b')
for i in range(c):
  letters.append('c')

shuffle(letters)
print(''.join(letters))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from random import choice

options = {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 1}
gen_chars = []
while options:
    genc = choice(''.join(options.keys()))
    options[genc] -= 1
    if options[genc] == 0:
        options.pop(genc)
    gen_chars.append(genc)

print(''.join(gen_chars))
```

Comment: Good, now you need to choose over all the answers to accept one which better fit with your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for variables A, B and C for int though:

```
 import random
 def generate_string(A, B, C):
     _list = list("a"*A + "b"*B + "c"*C)
     random.shuffle( _list)
     return "".join(_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Function:

```
def generate_string(A,B,C):
    from random import sample as sp
    return "".join(sp(("a"*A)+("b"*B)+("c"*C),A+B+C))
```

Using:

```
>>> generate_string(2,3,1)
'baacbb'
>>> generate_string(2,3,1)
'bcbaba'
>>> generate_string(5,1,1)
'baaacaa'
>>> generate_string(2,5,1)
'cbababbb'
>>>
```